# Android RadiGroup allows multiple selection

Tags: android, radio-group

Android API Level 24 (emulator) seems to allow multiple selection if I pre-select multiple RadioButton initially. I just want to know if this is a bug or not?

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/metal"
           android:checked="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/classical"
            android:checked="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/jazz"/>

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

The app launches like this:

[image]

And if I click on Jazz, it becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: Probably not a bug, I will explain so you checked two in xml but not set single choice, because of that the user can choice what he wants if you want user to only choice one make radio group single choice.

Comment: Try assigning `android:id` values to the `RadioButton` widgets. See [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36910867).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks, assigning id did the trick, the last one set as checked is checked in UI. Btw I was studying your book :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your layout lacks `android:id` values for the `RadioButton` widgets. That can work, if you're not starting with any of them pre-checked in the layout resource. If you are going to use `android:checked` in the layout resource, you need to assign widget IDs to the `RadioButton` widgets. This is [a long-standing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36910867) that is unlikely to change, so "it's just one of those things" that we have to deal with in Android app development.